How to use objects in C++ correctly
After finally having learnt most of the basics of C++, there is still on puzzle part which is missing. Let's take for example:
class MyClass {
/// ...
};

void f1(MyClass& cl) {
}

void main() {
  MyClass cl; // Calls the constructor
  MyClass *ptr = nullptr; // Declares a pointer.
  ptr = &cl;  // Now points to the object above.
  f1(cl); // working by mentioning the object
  f1(*ptr);  // working by dereferencing.
}

Now, I do not understand what to do when a function is returning a simple class name (not a pointer like MyClass * and not a reference like MyClass&:
MyClass f3() {
  MyClass c = nullptr; // is this even allowed?
  // .... Within the function, c gets assigned to some other already existing object.
  return c;
}

// caller:
MyClass c = f3();
MyClass *ptr = ?????; // <--- what comes here to invoke f3()?
MyClass& ref = ?????; // <--- what comes here to invoke f3()?

So, my question is, how to assign the return value of a function whose return value is of type MyClass (not pointer, not reference) to a pointer or a reference in the caller? Does MyClass obj = nullptr even make sense, or should I prefer modifying the function to return MyClass *?

So, my question is, how to assign the return value of a function whose return value is of type MyClass -- Did you actually try return c;?  You will see it will work, given that MyClass has correct copy semantics.  It looks like you are using other computer languages to figure out C++.

The correct way is to use them as little as possible and rely on move semantics and/or pass objects around by reference (like you already do) and then pointers are not necessary.  Only in the case that you have runtime polymorphism (virtual functions) are pointers really needed. And then you should use std::make_unique.

MyClass c = nullptr; // is this even allowed? It depends, if MyClass have a constructor that takes a std::nullptr_t object as argument, then it will work. Not otherwise, as C++ doesn't really have the concept of "null objects".

MyClass f3() { MyClass retval; return retval; }  and then auto myclass = f3(); is totally fine. And it will not result in a copy of retval being made (lookup copy elission/return value optimization)

As for the "what comes here to invoke f3()?" part, for both pointers and references, there is no way to do it. You can create a pointer to c, or a reference of c, but you can't invoke f3() in the initialization of either ptr or ref.

Regarding So, my question is, how to assign the return value of a function whose … : Store return value of function in reference C++

The answer to most of your questions (if not all of them) is to pretend that MyClass is an int or double.  What you see being done with int, double, etc. is basically the same thing that would be done with MyClass.  Unlike many other computer languages, C++ works using value-semantics, not reference semantics.


MyClass f3() {
  MyClass c = nullptr; // is this even allowed?
  // .... Within the function, c gets assigned to some other already existing object.
  return c;
}


In the above case, it doesn't make any sense because c is not a pointer.
Later c is returned by value, so a copy is made. This is easy is MyClass is a trivial class, but if the class has dynamically allocated memory you'll want to read up on the rule of three/five/zero.

"In the above case, it doesn't make any sense because c is not a pointer." ... Ok, so the outcome is: I should modify this function to MyClass *f3() { MyClass *c = nullptr; ... return c; }

Well, then you're just returning nullptr. Might as well write: MyClass *f3() { return nullptr; }

I would go so far as to say you should (almost) never return a raw pointer from a function.  The only exception would be for observing some sub-object of an object (i.e. std::string::c_str()) where the lifetime of the object pointed to is very well defined.

@Chris Well, of course, during the course of the function, c will be assigned some other object which already existed when entering that function.
